# Suppress first new line on list

Tags: lists, line-breaking

I want to make entries of the following type:

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}
```

I want entries to contain lists and create them like this:

```
\test{\MarginText{Some Margin Text A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
}

\test{\MarginText{Some Margin Text B}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
\end{itemize}
}
```

Now for example A, the margin text and the Lorem ipsum are horizontally aligned. For example B, the itemize introduces a newline, which is unwanted, destroying the horizontal alignment. I have tried parsep and the enumitem package and its inline options, but have gotten nowhere so far.

[image: Result]

Is it possible to suppress this newline?

Complete sample:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 


\newcommand{\test}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\begin{document}

\test{\MarginText{Some Margin Text A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
}

\test{\MarginText{Some Margin Text B}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First, use `marginnote` as it does better job. Second, move `\MarginText{Some Margin Text B}` inside `\item`.

```
\item \MarginText{Some Margin Text B} Lorem ipsum ....
```

If it is put outside (like you did), it is anchored in the upper line. Further, `\footnotesize{#1}` should be `\footnotesize#1`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page


\newcommand{\test}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize#1\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\begin{document}

\test{\MarginText{Some Margin Text A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
}

\test{%
\begin{itemize}
\item \MarginText{Some Margin Text B} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As additional information, I used this template: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv